# Get information using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell

Anyone who has used  powershell for SharePoint online to get all the info about Site Collection, sub sites, lists and library, and more for inventory purpose...please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint Online (SPO) Microsoft released [SharePoint Managment Shell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-c16941c3-19b4-4710-8056-34c034493429?CorrelationId=eec4cc2c-feaf-40f1-ab46-6a93c738d70b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102915057) that contains [Get-SPOSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161380(v=office.15).aspx) cmdlet to return one or more site collections.

Refer Vadim's Answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604076/use-powershell-to-retrieve-all-subsites-for-sharepoint-online)